# AWS Storage Gateway - Issue with Serial Console - KVM Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, kvm

I cannot get the KVM of AWS-Storage Gateway working,
I cannot access the configuration because the virsh console command always hangs at "Escape character is [^]" and I do not get the AWS Storage GW login prompt.

Can anyone help me?

Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is hard to understand what you are trying to do. Try to add more context. For example: copy and paste the commands you are running and the errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

It’s an issue with Ubuntu compatibility and virtio. We had to switch to centos. Still having performance issues compared to VMware SG vm. Support is not very helpful and they haven’t provided me with a best practice in terms of setup.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer I just saw it. I solved the issue but ironically cant remember how now... I didn switch to centos. will let you when I access the appliance what saved me. cheers